# Parsing the XML file having some unknown characters at starting

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser, parsing-error

I am trying to parse an xml file which is having some unknown characters at starting and i am getting the error

> isjava.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far

**Here is the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--RSS generated by RSSviaXmlTextWriter at Thu, 02 Mar 2017 16:35:42 GMT-->
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>The Tribune</title>
    <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/</link>
    <description>Tribune News Service</description>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/valley-schools-reopen-after-8-months/371227.html</link>
      <title>Valley schools reopen after 8 months</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/2017/3/2017_3$largeimg01_Wednesday_2017_232657586.jpg</image>
      <description>SRINAGAR: The schools in the Valley reopened fully today after remaining closed for eight months bringing back the liveliness that had been missing in the winter months. The schools were shut after the eruption of unrest following the killing of Hizbul commander Burhan Wani on July 8 last year.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 00:57:23 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/valley-schools-reopen-after-8-months/371227.html</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/registration-of-pilgrims-for-amarnath-yatra-begins/371228.html</link>
      <title>Registration of pilgrims for Amarnath yatra begins</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/2017/3/2017_3$largeimg01_Wednesday_2017_232805408.jpg</image>
      <description>JAMMU: Amid the chants of “Bham Bham Bhole”, the registration of pilgrims for this year’s pilgrimage to the Amarnath cave shrine commenced for both Baltal and Chandanwari routes here today.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 00:57:23 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/registration-of-pilgrims-for-amarnath-yatra-begins/371228.html</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/ladakh-worried-over-costly-air-travel-ahead-of-tourist-season/371235.html</link>
      <title>Ladakh worried over costly air travel ahead of tourist season</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/2017/3/2017_3$largeimg01_Wednesday_2017_233238395.jpg</image>
      <description>JAMMU: With Ladakh bracing up to host domestic and foreign tourists, the exorbitant air travel to the arid region continues to be a cause for worry for all stakeholders as the Civil Aviation Ministry is yet to make a formal commitment on “rationalisation of airfares” for Ladakh during peak tourist season from May to September.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 00:57:23 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/ladakh-worried-over-costly-air-travel-ahead-of-tourist-season/371235.html</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/take-steps-for-benefits-of-pilgrims-governor-tells-shrine-board-ceo/371220.html</link>
      <title>Take steps for benefits of pilgrims, Governor tells Shrine Board CEO</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/2017/3/2017_3$largeimg01_Wednesday_2017_232356489.jpg</image>
      <description>JAMMU: Governor NN Vohra today said several important issues related to Katra and its surrounding areas were conclusively addressed in the meeting held at Raj Bhawan on February 17 in which Chief Minister Mehbooba Mufti was also present.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 00:57:23 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/take-steps-for-benefits-of-pilgrims-governor-tells-shrine-board-ceo/371220.html</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/police-find-weapons-in-cross-loc-truck/371225.html</link>
      <title>Police find weapons in cross-LoC truck</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/archive/</image>
      <description>SRINAGAR: A cache of weapons, which was being smuggled for militants in the Kashmir valley, was recovered from a truck engaged in cross-LoC trade in north Kashmir’s Baramulla district, the police said today.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 00:57:23 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/police-find-weapons-in-cross-loc-truck/371225.html</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <category>Jammu &amp; Kashmir</category>
      <link>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/shutdown-in-bannihal-town-over-twin-deaths/371579.html</link>
      <title>Shutdown in Bannihal town over twin deaths</title>
      <image>http://images.tribuneindia.com/cms/gall_content/archive/</image>
      <description>JAMMU: A shutdown marred life in a Jammu and Kashmir town on Thursday amid allegations that the driver and a cleaner in a truck found dead in an accident had actually been murdered.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Mar 2017 13:28:31 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid>http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/jammu-kashmir/shutdown-in-bannihal-town-over-twin-deaths/371579.html</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I think the line number 2 creates the problem which is

```
<!--RSS generated by RSSviaXmlTextWriter at Thu, 02 Mar 2017 16:35:42 GMT-->
```

obviously the first line is treated as comment by the xmlpullparser but the issue is with the second line.
The Parser is i guess unable to parse the second line because it is searching for the starting tag and it does encounter the character **.**

Here is my parser

```
public class SitesXmlPullParserTribuneLocal{

    static final String KEY_SITE = "item";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_ABOUT = "description";
    static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "image";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";
    private static boolean firstCheck = true;


    public static List<NewsItems> getStackSitesFromFile(Context ctx) {

        // List of StackSites that we will return
        List<NewsItems> newsItems;
        newsItems = new ArrayList<NewsItems>();

        // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing
        NewsItems curNewsItems = null;


        // Temporary Holder for current text value while parsing
        String curText = "";

        try {
            // Get our factory and PullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("TribuneLocal.xml");
//            Log.e("ERROR at TribuneLocal", String.valueOf(ctx.openFileInput("TribuneLocal.xml")));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            // point the parser to our file.
            xpp.setInput(reader);

            // get initial eventType
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            Log.e("TagName Local", String.valueOf(eventType));


            //To get the actual location to start parsing from
            boolean actual_work = false;

            // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT
            Log.e("You Reached To", "Mark1");

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                // Get the current tag
                Log.e("You Reached To", "Mark2");
                String tagName = xpp.getName();
                Log.e("You Reached To", "Mark3");
//                Log.e("TagName is", tagName);
                // React to different event types appropriately
                if (eventType != XmlPullParser.START_TAG ) {
                    Log.e("EventType Inside", String.valueOf(eventType));
//                    firstCheck = false;
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    continue;
                }
                xpp.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#relaxed", true);

                Log.e("EventType Outside", String.valueOf(eventType));
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        Log.e("You Reached To", "Mark4");
                        if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SITE)) {
                            // If we are starting a new <news> block we need
                            //a new NewsItems object to represent it
                                actual_work = true;
                                curNewsItems = new NewsItems();
                        }

                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                        curText = xpp.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SITE) && actual_work) {
                            // if </item> then we are done with current Site
                            // add it to the list.
                            newsItems.add(curNewsItems);

                        } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME) && actual_work) {
                            // if </title> use setTitle() on curSite
                            Log.e("TITLE IS ",curText);

                            curNewsItems.setTitle(curText);

                        } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LINK) && actual_work) {
                            // if </link> use setLink() on curSite
                            Log.e("LINK IS ",curText);

                            curNewsItems.setLink(curText);
                        } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ABOUT) && actual_work) {
                            // if </description> use setDescription() on curSite
                            Log.e("DESCRIPTION IS ",curText);

                            curNewsItems.setDescription(curText);
                        } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DATE) && actual_work) {
                            // if </image> use setImgUrl() on curSite
                            Log.e("DATE IS  : ",curText);

                            curNewsItems.setDate(curText);
                        }else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL) && actual_work) {
                            // if </image> use setImgUrl() on curSite
                            Log.e("IMAGE IS  : ",curText);

                            curNewsItems.setImgUrl(curText);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                //move on to next iteration
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tribune Local File","There is an ERROR Parsing It");
        }

        // return the populated list.
        return newsItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're currently *assuming* that the encoding of the file is the same as the  default encoding. Why create a reader, when you can just set the input to the input stream? It also doesn't help that you've told us the *message* from the exception, but not the stack trace...

Comment: no problem for second line it is a comment !

Comment: @JonSkeet it was the only log message in the stack trace 
03-02 19:50:29.509 21723-21723/com.example.raqib.instadate E/exceptiom: isjava.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
03-02 19:50:29.509 21723-21723/com.example.raqib.instadate E/TagName Local: 0
03-02 19:50:29.509 21723-21723/com.example.raqib.instadate E/You Reached To: Mark1
03-02 19:50:29.509 21723-21723/com.example.raqib.instadate E/You Reached To: Mark2
03-02 19:50:29.509 21723-21723/com.example.raqib.instadate E/You Reached To: Mark3

So what is the issue with the parser?

Comment: @JonSkeet do you want to say there is encoding mismatch?

Comment: @vm345 where is the actual problem then

Comment: I'm saying there *could* be an encoding mismatch, and that using the platform default encoding is pretty much always a bad idea. The fact that your exception logging consists of "There is an ERROR parsing It" without reporting the exception doesn't help either. Have you debugged through this code? You should put the log into your question, too.

Comment: @JonSkeet i am a beginner, 
so what is the suggestion so that i could parse the file easily....

i am also having another file which also has utf-8 encoding and the same parser can parse it like a charm.

Comment: Well I've suggested debugging through your code and improving your error handling, for a start. (**Always** log the exception itself. Logging "something went wrong" is not helpful at all.) But for the encoding side, I've already suggested you could just call `setInput` with the `InputStream` - you don't need to create a reader.

Comment: i removed the reader and associated the file with input reader as 
**xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(ctx.openFileInput("TribuneLocal.xml")));**
But there is the same error again....

and on debugging i am unable to get the log
'Log.e("You Reached To", "Mark4");'
 present inside the switch case...

Comment: what are you trying to do ? parse xml (it seems ok to me) ? why dont you use a parser ? What are these "unkwnow" characters ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina i want to parse the xml file, but it gives the above mentioned exception.
i think it is because of line no 2.As this is not a standard comment in xml.
now my problem is how we can solve the issue.
what i started to do is that , convert the xml file to string, remove the first line and second line then converting the updated string back to xml and then parse it.
if you have a beeter solution please mention here.

Answer (score 0):

the xml file is ok

this parses the file, and then you can use the DOM and extract elements, ...

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // PARSE
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(fis)));
```